# Programmatically Write to Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

[firebase.admin()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin) does not seem to offer create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) operations on Firebase Hosting.

What would be the recommended way to write a file to Firebase Hosting programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no official SDK (as Doug says, the official API is REST-based), you can import `firebase-tools` into a Node.js script and use it like an API.

While neither of these officially allow you to deploy a single file, you can use it creatively to get what you want. See my Gist here: https://gist.github.com/puf/e00c34dd82b35c56e91adbc3a9b1c412, which gives you an command line tool like this:

```
node deployFile.js <site_name> <file_to_deploy> [commit]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your only available option at the moment is the [Firebase Hosting REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reference/rest/).  There are currently no public SDKs for this that I'm aware of.

Comment: The closest we have to an SDK is using `firebase-tools` as a library, which is akin having a Node.js SDK. I'll actually post an answer, since you *can* soft-of deploy a single file by some trickery.

Answer (score 1):

think one can only push deployments and manipulate their meta-data; not individual files within a deployment. creating new deployments would be the only way - or rolling them back. eg. when having an off-site staging area in `R/W` mode, this can be edited and then deployed as a new version, upon save. the [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) can be automated with any server-side scripting language.

Comment: the issue is Google Images Best Practices says to organize images in clean directory structures, e.g. `/fruits/apples/fuji` but I use cloud functions image resizing. ...HTTPS for CNAME [does not appear to be supported](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/troubleshooting#static-website).

Comment: @RonRoyston changing the `DNS` record type form `CNAME` to `A` might help (essential for `SSL`). within the context of Cloud Functions, one could use temporary storage as the off-site staging area: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system - and pull the latest version from the hosting, manipulate it and deploy it... also https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites could be used, to rewrite the host-name, in order to serve images directly from a bucket - or maintain an index of them in Realtime Database, so that one does not have to modify any `HTML`.